# SharePoint framework features

Tags: spfx-webparts

According to http://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/notes-on-solution-packaging you can provision content types and pages using the SP Framework app package.
What are the possibilities and impossibilities for this approach? Do the .spapp packages have the same power as an xml only sandboxed solution?
Related question: In the preview you have to upload the workbench.aspx page in order to use the SP framework. How will this work when it's live? Is it a new page layout that will be released that holds the new functionality or will it work on all pages by loading addtional client side scripting all through O365?

Thanks for your help.